# How do I select rows distinct on test_id with max timestamp and result

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I am sorry if the title is a bit confusing but here is my db table:

```
id  test_id   result    test_timestamp
1   5         1         2014-10-21 09:22:59
2   5         2         2014-10-21 09:25:12
3   7         3         2014-10-21 09:23:10
4   7         1         2014-10-21 09:19:51
5   7         2         2014-10-21 09:20:00
```

the thing I want to do is select distinct test_id with the latest timestamp and it's result, so the result would be this:

```
id  test_id   result    test_timestamp
2   5         2         2014-10-21 09:25:12
3   7         3         2014-10-21 09:23:10
```

I have no problem getting the test_id and timestamp

```
SELECT distinct(method_id), max(test_timestamp) from results  group by method_id
```

but when I want the result with it I get all the possible results with it's latest timestamp for the test_id, I know why I get this but i'm not sure how to solve it.

```
SELECT distinct(method_id), max(test_timestamp), result from results  group by method_id, result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PostgreSQL, [`DISTINCT ON` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) is the fastest and simplest way to do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (test_id)
       id, test_id, result, test_timestamp
  FROM results
 ORDER BY test_id, test_timestamp DESC, result;
```

Comment: thanks, this helped alot :D, the finished query ended up like this: `SELECT DISTINCT ON (r.test_id)
r.test_id, 
max(r.test_timestamp),
r.result
from results r 
group by r.test_id, r.result
order by r.test_id asc, max desc`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to use PostgreSQLs special **distinct on** syntax, here is the simple filter way:

```
SELECT  
id, test_id, result, test_timestamp
FROM results
where test_timestamp = (select max(test_timestamp) from results r2 where r2.test_id=results.test_id)
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f5be6/2/0

The difference appears, if one has two rows for one ***test_id*** with the same maximum ***test_timestamp***. Then this SQL delivers all rows for this maximum timestamp while `distinct on` only delivers the first one.